# Find the class of a field using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

We can use:

```
Class.getFields();
```

to find all fields listed by the enclosing class. I would like to do the reverse. Consider:

```
class x {
    Object sd = new Object();
}
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
sd.getSomethingClass();
```

and return x?

Comment: No. The value of `sd` could be stored in multiple fields, as well as in local variables. If you had a `java.lang.reflect.Field`, that would be a different matter... but using the expression `sd` will get the value of it.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for sd.getClass().getEnclosingClass(); ??

Comment: @jperis nope. I'm looking for the class that encloses the object, not the class definition.

Comment: There is no such thing as “enclosing the object”. For a *field* in scope, it makes no sense to try to get the the enclosing class via the field when the scope *is* the class. You can simply use `[ expression . ] getClass()` instead of `[ expression . ] field.getSomethingClass()`